# Unable to disable 3DES cipher in port 443

Tags: encryption, tls, certificate

I have disabled 3DES in registry. Port 3389 is successfully disable 3DES (TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA).

However, 3DES ciphers are still occur in port 443. What should be done to remove 3DES ciphers in port 443?

Thank you.

Disable 3DES:
[image: Disable 3DES]

3DES ciphers in port 443:
[image: 3DES ciphers in port 443]

No 3DES ciphers in port 3389:
[image: No 3DES ciphers in port 3389]

Comment: Interesting situation. Not sure this affects RDP, (it should, since it's all "schannel" in the background anyway I guess) but please try anyway: Have you tried disabling 3DES via [IISCrypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto) and rebooted?

Comment: @StackzOfZtuff Yes, I have tried to disable 3DES by IISCrypto and rebooted, but still occur these three 3DES ciphers in port 443. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Are you running something other than IIS on 443?

Comment: @StackzOfZtuff Yes, apache server is using port 443 for client to access into jedox web (a web interface of BI system).

Comment: @StackzOfZtuff Thanks for your reminder! I should mark '!3DES' on the SSLCipherSuite line in ssl.conf file.

Comment: Yes. There's also a nice generator that (among other settings) generates an old/intermediate/modern "SSLCipherSuite" line -> https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/